# relation between roots and coefficient in a cubic polynomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots, cubics

If $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ are roots of the cubic equation
$$2x^{3}+3x^2-x-1=0$$ then I want to find the equation whose roots are $\frac{\alpha}{\beta+\gamma}, \frac{\beta}{\gamma+\alpha}, \frac{\gamma}{\alpha+\beta}$.

I have $\alpha+\beta+\gamma$= - $\frac{3}{2}$.

Therefore roots become $\frac{\alpha}{-\frac{3}{2} -\alpha}$,$\frac{\beta}{-\frac{3}{2} -\beta}$, $\frac{\gamma}{-\frac{3}{2} -\gamma}$.

To find the equation we have to find their sums and products, but it looks like complicated.

Is their any easy trick ?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please edit your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.

Comment: Hint: $\beta+\gamma = -3/2 -\alpha$.

Comment: Hint: what is the polynomial with roots $\frac1\alpha,\frac1\beta,\frac1\gamma$? What is the polynomial with roots $\frac{-3/2}\alpha,\frac{-3/2}\beta,\frac{-3/2}\gamma$? What is the polynomial with roots $\frac{-3/2}\alpha-1,\frac{-3/2}\beta-1,\frac{-3/2}\gamma-1$?

Comment: Hint: Let $y=\frac{x}{-\frac{3}{2} -x}$. Write $x=g(y)$. Then $0=f(x)=f(g(y))$.

Comment: @lhf: I think your approach would make a nice solution.

Comment: @robjohn, done, thanks for the nudge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If
$$
2x^3+3x^2-x-1=0
$$
has roots $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$, then substituting $x\mapsto\frac1x$ (and multiplying by $-x^3$ to clear denominators)
$$
\begin{align}
&-x^3\left(\frac2{x^3}+\frac3{x^2}-\frac1x-1\right)\\
&=x^3+x^2-3x-2=0
\end{align}
$$
has roots $\frac1\alpha,\frac1\beta,\frac1\gamma$. Then substituting $x\mapsto-\frac23x$ (and multiplying by $-\frac{27}8$ to clear denominators)
$$
\begin{align}
&-\frac{27}8\left(\left(-\frac23x\right)^3+\left(-\frac23x\right)^2-3\left(-\frac23x\right)-2\right)\\
&x^3-\frac32x^2-\frac{27}4x+\frac{27}4=0
\end{align}
$$
has roots $\frac{-3/2}\alpha=\frac{\alpha+\beta+\gamma}\alpha,\frac{-3/2}\beta=\frac{\alpha+\beta+\gamma}\beta,\frac{-3/2}\gamma=\frac{\alpha+\beta+\gamma}\gamma$. Next, substituting $x\mapsto x+1$
$$
\begin{align}
&(x+1)^3-\frac32(x+1)^2-\frac{27}4(x+1)+\frac{27}4\\
&=x^3+\frac32x^2-\frac{27}4x-\frac12=0
\end{align}
$$
has roots $\frac{\beta+\gamma}\alpha,\frac{\alpha+\gamma}\beta,\frac{\alpha+\beta}\gamma$. Finally, substituting $x\mapsto\frac1x$ (and multiplying by $-4x^3$ to clear denominators)
$$
\begin{align}
&-4x^3\left(\frac1{x^3}+\frac32\frac1{x^2}-\frac{27}4\frac1x-\frac12\right)\\
&=2x^3+27x^2-6x-4=0
\end{align}
$$
has roots $\frac\alpha{\beta+\gamma},\frac{\beta}{\alpha+\gamma},\frac{\gamma}{\alpha+\beta}$.

Answer (score 3):

First, note that $\beta+\gamma = -\frac{3}{2} -\alpha$.

Now, let $y=\frac{x}{-\frac{3}{2} -x}=g(x)$. Then $x=h(y)= -\frac{3 y}{2 (y + 1)}$.

Therefore, if $z$ is a root of $f(x)$, then $w=g(z)$ is a root of $j(w)=f(h(w))$. Finally, clear the denominators in $j(w)=0$ to get a polynomial equation for $w$.

Comment: See [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2x%5E3%2B3x%5E2-x-1+where+x%3D-%5Cfrac%7B3+y%7D%7B2+%28y+%2B+1%29%7D).

Answer (score 0):

While this is *not* a general method for zeroes of a cubic polynomial, this *particular* polynomial is amenable to familiar methods.  We can apply the Rational Zeroes Theorem to find that one zero is  $ \ \alpha \ = \ -\frac12 \ \ , $ so we may factor $ \ 2x^3 + 3x^2 - x - 1 \ = \ \left(x + \frac12 \right)·2·(x^2 + x - 1) \ = \ 0 \ \ . $  This polynomial also has the helpful property that it has symmetry about $ \ x \ = \ -\frac12 \ \ : \ 2·\left(u - \frac12 \right)^3 + 3·\left(u - \frac12 \right)^2 - \left(u - \frac12 \right) - 1 $ $ = \ 2u·\left(u^2 - \frac54 \right) \ \ . $  The other zeroes of the original polynomial are then $ \ \beta \ , \ \gamma \ = \ \alpha \ \pm \ \Delta \ = \ -\frac12  \pm  \frac{\sqrt5}{2} \ \ . \ $  (We will have need of $ \ \Delta^2 \ = \ \frac54 \ $ shortly. These two zeroes are in fact $ \ \frac{1}{\phi} \ $ and $ \ -\phi \ \ , $ with $ \ \phi \ $ being the "Golden Ratio", but we won't be making use of that in this discussion.)

We seek a cubic polynomial with the transformed zeroes $$ \alpha' \  = \ \frac{\alpha}{\beta \ + \ \gamma} \  = \ \frac{-1/2}{-1} \ = \ \frac12 \ \ \ , \ \ \ \beta' \ = \ \frac{\beta}{\alpha \ + \ \gamma} \  = \ \frac{\alpha \ + \ \Delta}{2\alpha \ - \ \Delta} \ = \ \frac{1 \ + \ 2\Delta}{2 \ - \ 2\Delta} \ \ ,  $$
$$\gamma' \ = \ \frac{\gamma}{\alpha \ + \ \beta} \  = \ \frac{\alpha \ - \ \Delta}{2\alpha \ + \ \Delta} \ = \ \frac{1 \ - \ 2\Delta}{2 \ + \ 2\Delta} \ \ .  $$

From these, we compute the coefficients of a new *monic* polynomial from
$$ c' \ \ = \ \ -(\alpha'  ·  \beta'  ·  \gamma') \ \ = \ \ -\frac{(1 \ + \ 2\Delta)·(1 \ - \ 2\Delta)}{2 ·(2 \ - \ 2\Delta)·(2 \ + \ 2\Delta)} \ \ = \ \ \frac{4\Delta^2 \ - \ 1}{8 · (1 \ - \ \Delta^2)} $$ $$ = \ \ \frac{5 \ - \ 1}{-2} \ \ = \ \ -2 \ \ ; $$
$$ a' \ \ = \ \ -(\alpha' \ + \ \beta' \ + \ \gamma') \ \ = \ \ - \left[ \ \frac12 \ + \  \frac{1 \ + \ 2\Delta}{2 \ - \ 2\Delta} \ + \  \frac{1 \ - \ 2\Delta}{2 \ + \ 2\Delta} \ \right] \ \ = \ \ \frac32· \left(\frac{\Delta^2 \ + \ 1}{  \Delta^2 \ - \ 1} \right) $$ $$ = \ \ \frac32· \left(\frac{5 \ + \ 4}{  5 \ - \ 4} \right) \ \ = \ \ \frac{27}{2} \ \ ; $$
$$ \frac{b'}{c'} \ \ = \  \ \frac{\alpha' · \beta' \ +  \ \alpha' · \gamma' \ + \ \beta' · \gamma'}{- \ (\alpha'  · \beta'  ·  \gamma')} \ \ = \ \ - \left(\frac{1}{\alpha'} \ + \frac{1}{\beta'} \ + \ \frac{1}{\gamma'} \right) $$
$$ = \ \ - \left[ \ 2 \ + \  \frac{2 \ - \ 2\Delta}{1 \ + \ 2\Delta} \ + \  \frac{2 \ + \ 2\Delta}{1 \ - \ 2\Delta} \ \right] \ \ = \ \ \frac{6}{  4\Delta^2 \ - \ 1} \ \ = \ \ \frac{6}{ 5 \ - \ 1} \ \ = \ \ \frac32 $$
$$ \Rightarrow \ \ b' \ \ = \ \ \frac32 \ · \ (-2) \ \ = \ \ -3 \ \ . $$
A cubic polynomial having the transformed zeroes which has *integer* coefficients is then $ \ 2x^3 \ + \ 27x^2 \ - \ 6x \ - \ 4 \ \ . $